# Prove nontrivial conditional expectation relation

Tags: probability, functions

I wish to prove that for non-factorizable probability distribution function of two variables $W(x,y)\ne f(x)g(y)$ the conditional expectation value $E[y^2|x]$ is not constant (that is, has some $x$ dependence). It can be assumed that in general $W(x,y)\ne W(x,-y)$. Beside some general considerations I don't have a direction (this is not hw question, but arised as part of research). If it helps, $W(x,y)$ and its derivatives can be considered continuous.

Comment: Please do not modify significantly your question after answers addressing it are posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result does not hold. Here is an example such that $E(y^2\mid x)$ is constant but $(x,y)$ is not independent.

Choose some bounded independent random variables $x$ and $z$ such that $E(z)=0$, say, with $x$ uniform on $(0,1)$ and $z$ uniform on $(-1,1)$, and define $$y=\sqrt{1+zx}$$ Then $(x,y)$ is not independent since, for example,
$$P(y^2\geqslant\tfrac32\mid x)=\left(1-\tfrac1{2x}\right)\mathbf 1_{x>1/2}$$ depends on $x$, 
but $$E(y^2\mid x)=E(1+zx\mid x)=1+E(z)x=1$$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Thank you! Now we can proceed further - what are sufficient conditions for it to depend on $x$?

Comment: Sorry but this has no nontautological answer. So, no, we cannot "proceed further"...

Comment: Can you add the combined PDF $W(x,y)$ please?

Comment: What do you find difficult in writing down the joint PDF of $(x,y)$, starting from the PDF of $x$ (which is explicit) and the conditional PDF of $y^2$ conditionally on $x$?

Comment: Just out of practice

Comment: Seeing **me** practice won't help **you**, then.

Comment: Yet another revenge downvote. Happy reading!